# how to read "Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements." mat file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I have a problem with reading a large mat file containing 1x27184292 char.
I've tried many parsing and reading tools e.g. fileread, fopen, etc. but I couldn't open and read it.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: have you tried the Import Data tool under the Matlab / Home tab?

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried just calling `load()` on it? That's how you're supposed to read .mat files. Can you include the exact code you're using, and the exact error message you're getting? Hard to say what's going on without more details. Matlab can handle large .mat files just fine these days.